# NameError in Category#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is my category controller :

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index  
    @category = Category.all    
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    @category.save
    redirect_to @category   
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end

    def find_post
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

This is my index page where I want to show all my categories

```
<h1>ALL CATEGORIES</h1>
<% @category.each do |c|%>
  <ul><%= link_to c.name, categories_path(category) %></ul> 
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Add Category", new_category_path %>
```

These are the routes I have set for this controller

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
root 'category#index'
post '/category' => 'category#create'
get '/category/new' => 'category#new', as:'new_category'
get '/category/:id' => 'category#show', as:'categories'
```

end

Why I am getting this name error and how can I fix it ?

> undefined local variable or method `category' for` enter code
> here`#<#<Class:0x00007feddc03ad50>:0x00007fede47f8378>` Did you mean?
> `@category`

Comment: Hi @Pulkit Kumar, I believe your variable is `c` instead of `category`. Try this code: `<ul><%= link_to c.name, categories_path(c) %></ul>`. Also, I'd suggest you to read this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html for best practices.

Comment: thanks sir for your answer its solved by just passing c

Answer (score 1):

Please try to rename your file as `categories_controller.rb` and the class name should be `CategoriesController`.

As a rails convention controllers should be named in plural.

You can also change the routes to `resources :categories` instead of mapping each route to separate actions independently.